# Extract specific text from 2 different strings

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple csv files with names like:

```
'Transfer stab [22(3) _350-300-G22_; 24_04_2019 10_05_43].csv '
'Transfer lin [350-300-10-10(1) _good_; 02_05_2019 14_39_57].csv'
```

each file contains metadata that I want to extract and some data values:

```py
A               B                       C
Metadata    TestRecord.RecordTime    05/02/2019 15:31:34
Metadata    TestRecord.TestTarget    350-300-2-2    
MetaData    TestRecord.Remarks       bad
DataName    VG                       VD 
DataValue   -2                       3
DataValue   -1.9500000000000002      3  
...
...
```

I want to extract the name of **unique ID** of every file ex.(350-300-G22), however they are stored sometimes in **TestRecord.Remarks** other times in **TestRecord.TestTarget**.

Also the unique ID can have a comment attached to it like: "250-300-G23-60sec no light "
.

I have created a Dataframe with a remarks and a target column for all the csv files.

```py
date        filename                                                                    remarks                     target
04/24/2019  Transfer stab [22(3) _350-300-G22_; 24_04_2019 10_05_43].csv                350-300-G22                 22
05/02/2019  Transfer lin [350-300-10-10(1) _good_; 02_05_2019 14_39_57].csv             good                        350-300-10-10
04/24/2019  Transfer stab [25(3) _350-300-G25_; 24_04_2019 14_58_14].csv                350-300-G25                 25
04/23/2019  Transfer sat [(5) _250-300-G23-60sec no light_; 23_04_2019 11_26_55].csv    250-300-G23-60sec no light  None
04/23/2019  Transfer stab [(3) _250-300-G26_; 23_04_2019 12_02_37].csv                  250-300-G26                 None
```

I now want to create a new column with the unique ID values. I am thinking of something that passes a mask checking for '-' character and extracting everything around it.

Or finding in string this format ('nnn-nnn-lnn') where n=number and l=letter.

Ideally the final result would be a function that filters following a set of rules that I can add to cover all corner cases.